# Converting a series of bits into NSData object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, bit

How do I convert a series of 32 bits (representing 4 bytes) stored in an `NSString`, into an `NSData` object of 4 bytes in objective-c?

For example, how can I convert the following string:

```
NSString *bitSeries = @"00000000000000000000000111101100";
```

into `NSData` object with length precisely 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `strtoul()` with base 2 to convert the string to an unsigned integer:

```
NSString *bitSeries = @"00000000000000000000000111101100";
uint32_t value = strtoul([bitSeries UTF8String], NULL, 2);
```

and then create an `NSData` object:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
// Output: <ec010000>
```

Or, if you prefer big-endian byte order:

```
value = OSSwapHostToBigInt32(value);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
// Output: <000001ec>
```